# How to plot the 2D/3D projection of a high-dimension polyhedron defined by linear constraints in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Consider the region defined by a linear system of equalities and inequalities in Matlab, where the vector of unknowns, `x`, has size `30x1`.

For example, the system is `Aineq x <= bineq` and `Aeq x = beq`, where

```
clear
rng default 
Aineq=[randn(5,30); -eye(30); eye(30)]; 
bineq=[2*ones(5,1); zeros(30,1); ones(30,1)] ; 
Aeq=ones(1,30); 
beq=15;
```

Let `xj` denote the j-th component of `x`.

**Question:** I want to plot the region of values of `x1,x2` **for which there exists** `x3,...,x30` such that `x1,x2,x3,...,x30` satisfies `Aineq x <= bineq` and `Aeq x = beq`. Could you help to design a feasible strategy to do this?

**My idea:** The strategy I have tried is: (1) find the vertices of the feasible region of `Aineq x <= bineq` and `Aeq x = beq` using for example [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30892-analyze-n-dimensional-polyhedra-in-terms-of-vertices-or-in-equalities). (2) plot the vertices and fill the resulting convex region for the first two dimensions of `x`. I'm stuck at step (1): the dimension of my problem is prohibitive and the algorithm never ends.

**Remark:** I found some codes that can plot the feasibility region (for example, [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9261-plot-2d-3d-region?s_tid=mwa_osa_a)) provided that `x` is a `2x1` or `3x1` vector. I don't know how to apply them to my case, because the original `x` vector is `30x1`.

Comment: Can you provide your sample data `A, b, beq, Aeq, ub, lb`? Or do you expect us to invent something?

Comment: Thanks: I have made an example.

Comment: Your edited question now has nothing to do with linear programming. (I also don't think it's an SO question.) Indeed, I too think you should use the fact that the projection of a convex polyhedron on a plane is convex. But if you can't get the vertices, one thing you can do is to scan for plausible x1, x2, x3 brute force --- along some radial directions.

Answer (score -1):

For 2D, you can use [`area`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html) and [`fill`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) for a quick plot.

For 3D, [`fill3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill3.html) works. Otherwise, you can numerically partition the regions and use the basic plotting tools such as `plot3` and `surf`. [This implementation](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9261-plot-2d-3d-region) by Per Bergström does exactly that and is intended for use cases like yours.

Comment: @user3285148: I am happy to give some examples. Although, let's clarify some things first. I have interpreted that you want to plot a feasibility region of linear programming, by which I mean -- and it typically does -- that you start with the equations for one or multiple hyperplanes and see how the regions below (or above) all planes overlap. For that purpose, I find the use of `area`, `fill`, `surf` and Bergström's function straight-forward. Although I am happy to go over the use of the built-in functions if that's what you need. Bergström's package has its own documentations.

Comment: @user3285148: Matlab also has a [linear programming solver](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html). That doesn't really have much to do with what I thought people would typically mean by feasible regions from linear programming.

Comment: @user3285148: All you get is a minimum of a linear function under linear constrains. I assumed you don't mean that. Because projecting a single vector is trivial.

Comment: @user3285148: Let me know where you are.

Comment: @user3285148: I still think all you need is a method to plot inequalities regions. In your edited question, the ranks of `A` and `Aeq` are meant to be different right?